# Google analytics - track user from different url's

Tags: wordpress, web, google-analytics, pixel, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to calculate the ROI (return on investment) of my network.
We have adds from Facebook, Adwords, Taboola and Outbrain that goes to a wordpress site. Then, there is a button that goes to our Landings engine that is where the client buy our products.

There is a success page but it is from the landings engine.

A kind of graphic was:
advertisement -> wp -> landing (with form) -> landing success.

In analytics I want to see in Acquisition -> AdWords -> campaigns, the ROI.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's really only a couple of ways to do this that I can see:

1 If you have access to the template code for the external form and success pages you can add your analytics code snippet with your ID, and then use a ga() call to send a pageview for those urls. If the form is an ajax form that doesn't reload the page on success...you'll need to be able to tie into some sort of "onsuccess" handler to send the ga() call with a virtual pageview...something like '/external-form/thankyou/' or whatever.

2 If you don't have access to the form code, but the form allows you to re-direct on success...re-direct them to a "thank you" page on your own site.

Then...in Google Analytics, setup a goal conversion based on a "destination url."

Comment: Thx Kevin! i want to add thart i'm using google tag manager for events and triggers. 
I have all access for both systems.
So what you say it's possible to track this just adding the analytics code snippet ?

Comment: It is possible using Tag Manager, but it's crucial to know whether they are submitted using a standard `form` tag and a page refresh, or are they ajax forms (meaning submitted via JS and the page doesn't refresh)? -- the setup is different for each.